# possible to target iframe in another html file?

Tags: php, html

Is something like this possible:

```
      <form method="post" action="myphp.php" name="myname" target="another_html/iframe_name">???
```

I want the php file to display its results in an iframe inside another html file...

Thanks

Comment: Where is the other html file located? Is it open already?

Comment: no, closed, its located in same directory on same server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less like this:

```
<form method="post" action="Otherfile.php" name="myname" target="OtherFrame">
```